# Angular - $stateparams always undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to use stateParams as a filter for an ng-repeat. Im trying to create user profile pages where when someone visits the url

```
http://localhost:3000/users/johnexample
```

they will see a list of johnexample's "Savings". If i visit the url now i can see the profile page fine but the param doesnt initialise.

Im trying to setup the controller variable to filter by using

```
$scope.usernamevalue = $stateParams.username;
```

Thats always undefined when i visit the url

Client Controller

```
angular.module('savings').controller('SavingsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams','$state' , 'Users',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $window, $state, $http, Authentication, Users) {

    $scope.usernamevalue = $stateParams.username;

]);
```

Route

```
app.route('/api/savings/of/:username')
        .get(savings.listOf);
```

Server controller

```
exports.listOf = function(req, res) { Saving.find( { user: req.params.userid }).sort('-created').exec(function(err, posts) {

    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        console.log(req.params.userid);
        res.jsonp(posts);
    }
});
};
```

Is there anything else that i am missing with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're injecting dependencies in Angular, the order of the function arguments needs to match the order of the strings in the array. As it stands you're injecting the `$http` service with the name `$stateParams`, hence the error.

Comment: Thats brilliant. I was trying to figure that out for longer than id like to admit. 5 mins before i can accept the answer.

Comment: I've made that mistake far too many times, it's an easy one to not spot! Especially if it's a function with a lot of dependencies like this one.